# How can I find all the unused and uncategorized pages and images in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to find all pages that are both unused and uncategorized.

I can check them separately with the following API calls

```
api.php?action=query&list=querypage&qppage=Unusedimages

api.php?action=query&list=querypage&qppage=Uncategorizedimages
```

But I can't figure out how to find the intersection between the two queries.

Any advice? Or is there a different way to go about it?

Comment: Can't you just run both queries and then compute the intersection by yourself? I think that's the best solution here.

Comment: I was trying to see if the solution was possible WITHOUT coding. Guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution, so I made an extension. It creates two special pages:

- Unused and uncategorized files
- Unused and uncategorized pages

[Here's the extension's page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUnusedUncategorized) (the source is in the bitbucket link)

Comment: **This extension has been archived.**

This extension has not been maintained for some time, and no longer supports recent releases of MediaWiki.
[To see the page before archival, click here.](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:PermanentLink/5005431)